# Sincronizar 2 tablas con claves foráneas desde SQLite a PostgreSQL en Android

Tags: android, postgresql, sqlite, webservice

Tengo una aplicación en Android que se utiliza fuera de línea en la granja. Dentro de ella tengo una pequeña base de datos que almacena datos temporales que son recolectados en la granja y que luego son sincronizados con PostgreSQL mediante un web service.

En SQLite, la tabla A tiene una clave foránea a la tabla B.

```
Tabla A       Tabla B
id    fk      id
1     3       1
2     1       2
3     3       3
4     2
5     1
```

Debo insertar esta información en PostgreSQL. ¿Cómo lo hago?
Los ID de la tabla B cambiarán al ser insertados en PostgreSQL, quedando algo de este estilo.

PostgreSQL:

```
Tabla B
id
17839
17840
17841
```

¿Cómo debo estructurar los datos para mantener las claves foráneas actualizadas una vez sincronizados los datos de la tabla B?

Comment: Bueno, actualmente tengo tiempo de estar trabajando con aplicaciones móviles híbridas, ya he usado SQLite y MySQL, mi pregunta, es por que debe ser diferente la tabla B que tienes en tu servidor usando como gestor de DB a PostgreSQL, y también dime que se supone que almacena la tabla A y la B para poderte dar una ayuda completa

Comment: El tema es que mientras el usuario este offline recolectando datos en la granja, hay múltiples usuarios realizando inserciones en la tabla b del servidor, entonces cuando este usuario sincronice sus datos, evidentemente los ID no irán correlativos a la tabla b del servidor. Imaginate la tabla A como si fueran vacunas y la tabla B como si fueran personas

Comment: entonces, según entiendo, no estas creando perfiles ni nada de eso, o eso no va a existir, ya que según veo deberías hacer eso.

Comment: Todo eso existe. La solución que encontré fue sincronizar la tabla B y devolver a la aplicación los ID insertados en PostgreSQL. De esta manera, podía saber las claves foráneas de la tabla A una vez sincronizados los datos. Saludos.

Comment: Pues sinceramente, no veo eso lo mas correcto, a menos que este entendiendo mal, vas a mandar tu los ID desde la base de datos en tu servidor hacia el teléfono, pero no es mas fácil algún tipo de ID auto incremento y que solo sea enviar los datos JSON y recibirlos y almacenarlos y seguir un patrón, si entendí bien pues??